# Kafka consumer not appending consumed data into list in docker/ docker compose

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile

I developed a python app that reads file, transform it after that send it to Kafka topic and receive data with consumer. I deployed this pipeline with docker and docker compose. But according to logs. Here, it sent data to Kafka topic and consumer can receive data line-by-line but when code comes to [msg.value for msg in consumer] line, it does not append data into list. I build 3 containers for zookeeper, broker and client(which has three python scripts.)
Following is my docker-compose.yml file;

```
---
version: '3.5'

networks: 
  rmoff_kafka:
    name: rmoff_kafka

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    networks: 
      - rmoff_kafka
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.0
    container_name: broker
    ports: 
      - 9092:9092
    networks: 
      - rmoff_kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  client:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
      - broker
    networks: 
      - rmoff_kafka
```

And following is my Dockerfile for client ;

```
FROM python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "consumer.py"]
```

Following is part of my Kafka producer script;

```
def produce_data_with_kafka(data):
    """
    Kafka Producer writes data to topic.
    Args:
        data: dataframe: input dataframe
    Returns: None
    """
    try:
        logger.info("Kafka Producer setting up...")
        producer = KafkaProducer(
            bootstrap_servers=['broker:9092'],
            value_serializer=lambda x: json.dumps(x, default=str).encode("utf-8")
        )
    except Exception:
        raise Exception("Error when setting up Kafka Producer!")

    for row in data.values:
        producer.send("topic_test", key=None, value=row.flatten().tolist())
        producer.flush()

    logger.info("Data sent to Kafka topic...")
```

And following is part of my Kafka consumer script;

```
def consume_data_with_kafka():
    """
    Kafka Consumer read data from topic.
    Args: None 
    Returns:
        data: dataframe: input dataframe
    """
    try:
        logger.info("Kafka Consumer setting up...")
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
                "topic_test",
                bootstrap_servers=['broker:9092'],
                value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode("utf-8")),
                auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                enable_auto_commit=False
            )   
        consumer.subscribe(["topic_test"])
        result = pd.DataFrame(
            [msg.value for msg in consumer],
            columns=my_cols,
        )
        consumer.commit()
        return result
    except Exception:
        raise Exception("Error when setting up Kafka Producer!")
```

Finally following are client logs from docker-compose when I run client container;

```
2023-03-16 01:18:15 2023-03-15 22:18:15,648 - Stream Data Processing - Data Processer File - INFO - Reading raw data from input...
2023-03-16 01:18:15 2023-03-15 22:18:15,671 - Stream Data Processing - Data Processer File - INFO - Preprocessesing input data...
2023-03-16 01:18:15 2023-03-15 22:18:15,766 - Stream Data Processing - Data Processer File - INFO - Finding session ids for unique ips...
2023-03-16 01:18:17 2023-03-15 22:18:17,548 - Stream Data Processing - Data Processer File - INFO - Finding average times for unique session ids...
2023-03-16 01:18:19 2023-03-15 22:18:19,964 - Stream Data Processing - Data Processer File - INFO - Merging get_post_counts data with two times transformed data...
2023-03-16 01:18:19 2023-03-15 22:18:19,964 - Stream Data Processing - Data Processer File - INFO - Finding get and post counts for unique ips...
2023-03-16 01:18:19 2023-03-15 22:18:19,976 - Stream Data Processing - Kafka Producer File - INFO - Kafka Producer setting up...
2023-03-16 01:18:19 2023-03-15 22:18:19,978 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: connecting to broker:9092 [('172.31.0.3', 9092) IPv4]
2023-03-16 01:18:19 2023-03-15 22:18:19,978 - kafka.conn - INFO - Probing node bootstrap-0 broker version
2023-03-16 01:18:19 2023-03-15 22:18:19,978 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
2023-03-16 01:18:20 2023-03-15 22:18:20,097 - kafka.conn - INFO - Broker version identified as 2.5.0
2023-03-16 01:18:20 2023-03-15 22:18:20,097 - kafka.conn - INFO - Set configuration api_version=(2, 5, 0) to skip auto check_version requests on startup
2023-03-16 01:18:20 2023-03-15 22:18:20,269 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=1 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: connecting to broker:9092 [('172.31.0.3', 9092) IPv4]
2023-03-16 01:18:20 2023-03-15 22:18:20,269 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=1 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
2023-03-16 01:18:20 2023-03-15 22:18:20,270 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=broker:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: Closing connection. 
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,161 - Stream Data Processing - Kafka Producer File - INFO - Data sent to Kafka topic...
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,161 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=1 host=broker:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: Closing connection. 
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,163 - Stream Data Processing - Kafka Consumer File - INFO - Kafka Consumer setting up...
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,163 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: connecting to broker:9092 [('172.31.0.3', 9092) IPv4]
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,164 - kafka.conn - INFO - Probing node bootstrap-0 broker version
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,164 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,368 - kafka.conn - INFO - Broker version identified as 2.5.0
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,369 - kafka.conn - INFO - Set configuration api_version=(2, 5, 0) to skip auto check_version requests on startup
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,369 - kafka.consumer.subscription_state - INFO - Updating subscribed topics to: ('topic_test',)
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,369 - kafka.consumer.subscription_state - WARNING - subscription unchanged by change_subscription(['topic_test'])
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,425 - kafka.consumer.subscription_state - INFO - Updated partition assignment: [TopicPartition(topic='topic_test', partition=0)]
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,426 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=1 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: connecting to broker:9092 [('172.31.0.3', 9092) IPv4]
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,426 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=1 host=broker:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: Connection complete.
2023-03-16 01:18:36 2023-03-15 22:18:36,426 - kafka.conn - INFO - <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=broker:9092 <connected> [IPv4 ('172.31.0.3', 9092)]>: Closing connection.
```

I am missing one point, but could not find it.

Comment: what exactly is not working as expected? The code and logs seem fine, to me.

Comment: Here, it sent data to Kafka topic and consumer can receive data line-by-line but when code comes to [msg.value for msg in consumer] line, it does not append data into list.